# AngularJS ng-repeat column aware table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following model: `Item` : {data: String, schedule: DateTime, category: String}

I need to display a report of this data in the following way:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Time Range</th>
      <th>Category 1</th>
      <th>Category 2</th>
      <th>No Category</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6:00 - 2:30</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So I will need to compile and filter the list of Items into the time ranges and display the totals based on categories. How can I accomplish this with angular and tell which column I am in (and therefore choose the right value to display) as the categories are dynamic.

EDIT: The table will display a summary of all Items. So you'll have take all items and compile it into the form `Time Range`, `# In Category 1`, `# In Category 2`, `# In No Category`. The only thing that will be set by me is the time ranges.

I plan to store this data in a hash map where the keys are the category names, but I need to know which column I am in as the categories are dynamic. The categories come from the database (a user putting these items in).

Comment: Can you show data in a format that makes sense? What you said does not map to what you want the output to be...

Comment: Not clear what source of these dynamic categories is or what compile into date ranges really entails. Provide better data sample and expected results

Comment: Even with edited question there isn't enough information given to figure out what exactly it is that needs to be done

Comment: How do you know which category the data belongs to in your items if the categories are dynamic?

Comment: @IgnacioVillaverde You would get the categories from all of the items. For example: `SELECT * FROM ITEMS` would have the category. You could then say var categories = items.map(function(item) { return item.category});

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to do two things. Group list by category and display grouped list. See JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vittore/mmvxbcjx/4/

In order to group list you can use `array.reduce`. Convenient data structure for that would be hash of hashes, ie

```
var hash = { 
   '6:30': {
      category1: 5
   }
}
```

(Say you are grouping datetime based on time with an hour step.)

In order to get structure like that with reduce you will do:

```
var myList = [{},....];

$scope.grouped = list.reduce(function(a, d) {
  var hours = d.schedule.getHours();

  if (!(hours in a)) a[hours] = {}

  var timeSlot = a[hours]

  timeSlot[d.category || 'no category' ]  = 
      1 + ( timeSlot[d.category || 'no category'] | 0)

  return a;
}, {})
```

After you've got desired structure you need to do nested ng-repeat with angular:

```
<tr>
  <th>time slot</th>
  <th ng-repeat='c in categories'>{{ c }} </th>
  <th>no category</th>
</tr>

<tr  ng-repeat='(k,v) in grouped'>
  <th>{{ k }} : 00</th>
  <td ng-repeat='c in categories'>{{ v[c] }} </td>
  <td>{{ v['no category'] }}</td>
</tr>
```